# I can't see continuously the last insert data from my MySQL database to my html page

Tags: python, html, mysql, flask, last-insert-id

I use flask framework and with this code i get the last insert data,but i want to display continuously the last insert. When i reboot the flask framework i get it.Any help?

app.py

```
@app.route("/sensor" , methods=['POST','GET'])
def sensor():
   
   cursor = db.cursor()

   cursor.execute("SELECT Id,temperature,humidity FROM Bseonsor WHERE Id=(SELECT MAX(Id) FROM Bseonsor)")

   results = cursor.fetchall()
   
   return render_template('sensor.html',results=results)
```

sensor.html

```
<div>
    <table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
    {% for row in results %}
        <tr> {{ row[1] }} {{ row[2] }} </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. You can edit your questions to update them with requested information. I took the code from your comment to the question for you. Please make sure to take the [tour] and read [ask] to get started with this community. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe when making selections to the database, you should use the `buffered=True` argument.

Note about selections: *Also in the above program, the specified the size is 2 to fetch two records. Also, we set buffered=True in connection. Cursor () method to avoid MySQL Unread result error.*

[About mysql-connector selections](https://pynative.com/python-mysql-select-query-to-fetch-data/)

It should look something like this: `cursor = db.cursor(buffered=True)`
This can be a bit of a pain when trying to use prepared SQL though.

Comment: I got an error TypeError: cursor() got an unexpected keyword argument 'buffered'

Comment: Strange. Maybe you're using a different library. Do you get any errors when selecting usually?

Comment: no it work fine but it doesn't change the value when i insert new data